# PhoneTextBox and LengthIndicatorVisible bug

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

What I need to achieve is very simple. I have the following PhoneTextBox in a Windows Phone 8 application. When the TextBox has focus I need the LengthIndicatorVisible to be true and when it loses focus i don't want it there.

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="TextBox1" MaxLength="480" GotFocus="TextBox1_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox1_LostFocus"/>
```

The focus methods are as follow:

```
private void TextBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.LengthIndicatorVisible = true;
    TextBox1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
}

private void TextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.LengthIndicatorVisible = false;
    TextBox1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
}
```

When it gets focused and I type something the Length Indicator is displayed as it should. Now when it loses its focus even though the LostFocus() method is being called the Length Indicator remains.

Also if I put an ActionIcon the textbox size due to TextWrapping gets bigger but when the text is cleared it does NOT return to its default size (height actually)

I have searched around for similar behavior but it is said to have been fixed on the latest release (the one i use - [Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)).

Anyone has a clue of what is wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so it's a bug in the NuGet version but not in the latest source?

Comment: @NeilTurner from what I understood this is a bug generally..the latest source is the NuGet version - last update was 2 months ago - nothing more since then, at least that is what I found

Comment: I would file an issue on the WP Toolkit codeplex site in the meantime

Comment: Issue added [here](https://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/11208)

Comment: have you tried the latest August 2013 release of the WP Toolkit? also, [the source code is slightly ahead of the NuGet release](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

Comment: @NeilTurner I have tried it just now with many different way and STILL the same issue/bug. Indicator won't properly hide after TextBox loses the focus and its size after you set an action icon grows to match the size of the MaxLength property and NEVER resets.